# why armadillo matrix computation is much slower than Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, armadillo

I try to rewrite codes from Fortran to C++ with the matrix implements through Armadillo library. The result is the same for both codes, but the C++ code is much slower than Fortran(> 10x). The codes involve small matrix (2x2, 4x4) inverse, multiplication and addition. I put a part of the similar code here for testing.

============================

```
clang++ cplusplus.cc -o cplusplus --std=c++14 -larmadillo -O2

ifort fort.f90 -o fort -O2
```

C++ code time:   0.39404s

Fortran code time: 0.068s

============================

C++ code:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const int niter = 1580000;
  const int ns = 3;
  arma::cx_cube m1(2, 2, ns), m2(2, 2, ns), m3(2, 2, ns);
  arma::wall_clock timer;
  timer.tic();
  for (auto i=0; i<niter; ++i) {
    for (auto j=0; j<ns; ++j)
      m1.slice(j) += m2.slice(j) * m3.slice(j);
  }
  double n = timer.toc();
  std::cout << "time: " << n << "s" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Fortran code:

```fortran
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ns = 3, niter = 1580000
  complex*16 m1(2, 2, ns), m2(2, 2, ns), m3(2, 2, ns)
  integer i, j
  real :: start, finish
  call cpu_time(start)
  do i = 1, niter
     do j = 1, ns
        m1(1, 1, j) = m1(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        m1(1, 2, j) = m1(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
        m1(2, 1, j) = m1(2, 1, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        m1(2, 2, j) = m1(2, 2, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
     end do
  end do
  call cpu_time(finish)
  print *, "time: ", finish-start, " s"

end program main
```

====================================================================

following @ewcz @user5713492 advice

============================

```
clang++ cplusplus.cc -o cplusplus --std=c++14 -larmadillo -O2

ifort fort.f90 -o fort -O2

ifort fort2.f90 -o fort2 -O2
```

C++ code(cplusplus.cc) time:   0.39650s

Fortran code(fort.f90) (explicitly operation) time: 0.020s

Fortran code(fort2.f90) (matmul) time: 0.064s

============================

C++ code(cplusplus.cc):

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
  const int niter = 1580000;
  const int ns = 3;
  arma::cx_cube m1(2, 2, ns, arma::fill::ones),
    m2(2, 2, ns, arma::fill::ones),
    m3(2, 2, ns,arma::fill::ones);
  std::complex<double> result;
  arma::wall_clock timer;
  timer.tic();
  for (auto i=0; i<niter; ++i) {
    for (auto j=0; j<ns; ++j)
      m1.slice(j) += m2.slice(j) * m3.slice(j);
  }

  double n = timer.toc();
  std::cout << "time: " << n << "s" << std::endl;
  result = arma::accu(m1);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Fortran code(fort.f90):

```fortran
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ns = 3, niter = 1580000
  complex*16 m1(2, 2, ns), m2(2, 2, ns), m3(2, 2, ns)
  integer i, j
  complex*16 result
  real :: start, finish
  m1 = 1
  m2 = 1
  m3 = 1
  call cpu_time(start)
  do i = 1, niter
     do j = 1, ns
        m1(1, 1, j) = m1(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        m1(1, 2, j) = m1(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
        m1(2, 1, j) = m1(2, 1, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        m1(2, 2, j) = m1(2, 2, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
     end do
  end do
  call cpu_time(finish)
  result = sum(m1)
  print *, "time: ", finish-start, " s"
  print *, result

end program main
```

Fortran code(fort2.f90):

```fortran
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ns = 3, niter = 1580000
  complex*16 m1(2, 2, ns), m2(2, 2, ns), m3(2, 2, ns)
  integer i, j
  complex*16 result
  real :: start, finish
  m1 = 1
  m2 = 1
  m3 = 1
  call cpu_time(start)
  do i = 1, niter
     do j = 1, ns
        m1(:,:,j) = m1(:,:,j)+matmul(m2(:,:,j),m3(:,:,j))
     end do
  end do
  call cpu_time(finish)
  result = sum(m1)
  print *, "time: ", finish-start, " s"
  print *, result

end program main
```

======================================================================

The complex number may be one of the reasons that armadillo is so slow. If I use `arma::cube` instead of `arma::cx_cube` in C++ and use `real*8` in Fortran, the time is:

C++ code time: 0.08s

Fortran code(fort.f90) (explicitly operation) time: 0.012s

Fortran code(fort2.f90) (matmul) time: 0.028s

However, complex number is necessary for my computation. It's strange that 
computation time increases very large for armadillo library but a little for Fortran.

Comment: Why is your C++ inner loop not using `i` at all? Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @mikkola This is the simplified version of my codes that i means a lot of iterations. The operations are the same between Fortran and C++, but C++ is much slower than Fortran. That's the problem.

Comment: Why do you believe the Fortran compiler will doo all the computing when you don't use the result anywhere?

Comment: Should have remembered that in the C++ tag one can hunt a lot of rep for such a simple thing and answered...

Comment: C and C++ has some silly rules for handling complex arithmetic. See e.g. C11 Annex G. If you were to use g++ instead of clang, there is the -fcx-fortran-rules that would make it follow Fortran rules. See also -fcx-limited-range. -ffast-math might do the trick for clang, but it's quite a blunt instrument.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't timing anything in gfortran. It can see at level -O2 that you don't use the value of m1 so it skips the calculation entirely. Also in Fortran your arrays are uninitialized so you could be doing calculations with NaNs which might slow things down considerably.

So you should initialize your arrays and use some kind of input like the command line, user input, or file contents so the compiler can't precompute the results.

Then you might consider changing the loop contents in Fortran to

```
m1(:,:,j) = m1(:,:,j)+matmul(m2(:,:,j),m3(:,:,j))
```

So as to be consistent with the C++ stuff. (gfortran seemed to slow down a lot when doing this but ifort was quite happy with it.)

Then you **MUST** print out your arrays at the end so the compiler doesn't conclude that the loop you are timing can be skipped as gfortran did. Edit in the fixes and let us know about the new results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I update the question, and add initialization and the use of m1.

Comment: Oh, one last thing: in the Fortran code the compiler can see that arrays m2 and m3 don't change in the loop body and pull the MATMULs out of the loop. You might try inserting `call sub(m2)` in the loop and link to a separately compiled file sub.f90 that just says `subroutine sub(x);complex*16 x(*);end`. That way the compiler won't optimize away the MATMULs.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your Fortran version profits significantly in this particular example from expanding the matrix multiplication explicitly into elementary operations. In order to demonstrate this, let's assume following modification:

```
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: ns = 3, niter = 1580000
  complex*16 m1(2, 2, ns), m2(2, 2, ns), m3(2, 2, ns)
  integer i, j
  real :: start, finish
  call cpu_time(start)
  m2 = 1
  m3 = 1
  do i = 1, niter
     do j = 1, ns
        !m1(1, 1, j) = m1(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        !m1(1, 2, j) = m1(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(1, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
        !m1(2, 1, j) = m1(2, 1, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 1, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 1, j)
        !m1(2, 2, j) = m1(2, 2, j) + m2(2, 1, j) * m3(1, 2, j) + m2(2, 2, j) * m3(2, 2, j)
        m1(:, :, j) = m1(:, :, j) + MATMUL(m2(:, :, j), m3(:, :, j))
     end do
  end do
  WRITE(*, *) SUM(m1)
  call cpu_time(finish)
  print *, "time: ", finish-start, " s"
```

Here, at the end, the program prints the sum of `m1` in order to make at least partially sure that the entire loop is not eliminated. With the explicit multiplication (and `-O2`), I get running time of roughly 0.05s while with the general `MATMUL` it's roughly 0.2s, i.e., similar to the Armadillo approach...

Also, even though Armadillo is heavily template based so lots of the functions calls with respect to creating the subcube views via `slice()` might get eliminated, you still in principle have some overhead while with Fortran, you are directly manipulating continuous chunks of memory.

Comment: More likely explanatiin, we don't see a zero time after all.

Comment: I modified the codes as you suggest, and the big difference between c++ and Fortran remains the same.